# Linking Api's openURL with schema tel error in iPad

Tags: ipad, react-native, react-native-ios

I am using the following code...

```
openPhoneDialler(mobile) {
    let url = 'tel:' + mobile;
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (!supported) {
        throw 'Cant open phone dialler';
      } else {
        return Linking.openURL(url);
      }
    }).catch(err =>
      Alert.alert('Error','Error occurred',[{text: 'OK', onPress: () => {}}])
    );
  }
```

I am testing on an iPad without SIM card feature (Wifi only) , the canOpenURL gets resolved and the Linking.openURL(url) is called which shows an Alert with the mobile number and two options 'Cancel' and 'Call'. When I press 'Call' the alert gets closed and nothing happens which is expected since it is Wifi only iPad.

> But when I press 'Cancel' the app crashes with the following error screen

```
JSON value '{
    code = EUNSPECIFIED;
    domain = RCTErrorDomain;
    framesToPop = 1;
    nativeStackIOS =     (
        "0   workforce_mobile                    0x00000001000d4d00 RCTJSErrorFromCodeMessageAndNSError + 152",
        "1   workforce_mobile                    0x0000000100053e4c __41-[RCTModuleMethod processMethodSignature]_block_invoke_2.224 + 192",
        "2   workforce_mobile                    0x000000010015e2f0 -[RCTLinkingManager openURL:resolve:reject:] + 352",
        "3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018164ce80 <redacted> + 144",
        "4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001815422b4 <redacted> + 292",
        "5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000181546e7c <redacted> + 60",
        "6   workforce_mobile                    0x0000000100055098 -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 1704",
        "7   workforce_mobile                    0x00000001000aea54 -[RCTBatchedBridge callNativeModule:method:params:] + 568",
        "8   workforce_mobile                    0x00000001000addf4 __33-[RCTBatchedBridge handleBuffer:]_block_invoke.477 + 1276",
        "9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001804fe9e0 <redacted> + 24",
        "10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001804fe9a0 <redacted> + 16",
        "11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018050cad4 <redacted> + 928",
        "12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001805022cc <redacted> + 884",
        "13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018050ea50 <redacted> + 540",
        "14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000018050e7d0 <redacted> + 124",
        "15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001807071d0 _pthread_wqthread + 1096",
        "16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000180706d7c start_wqthread + 4"
    );
    userInfo = "<null>";
}' of type NSDictionary cannot be converted to NSString
```

> Note: the same crash also happens when u leave the alert open for around 10 seconds without any press.

Tested on : iPad (Wifi only and physical device) OS version 10.3.1

**Is this a bug in React-Native Linking Api or with the above code.**

Answer (score 0):

`Linking.openUrl` returns a promise object. By pressing the *Cancel* button, you cause the promise to be rejected.  Just add a catch to swallow the rejected promise.

`Linking.openUrl().catch(() => null)`

Here's the documentation about that:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html#openurl

Comment: but I am using  `return Linking.openURL(url)` which returns that promise to the outer catch, which should catch right.